# Create self signed SSL certificates in Python

Tags: python, ssl, m2crypto

I am trying to *generate* self signed SSL certificates using Python, so that it is platform independent. My target is the *.pem format.

I found [this script](http://sunh11373.blogspot.com/2007/04/python-utility-for-converting.html) that generates certificates, but no information how to self-sign them.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/256405/programmatically-create-x509-certificate-using-openssl

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The script you've linked doesn't create self-signed certificate; it only creates a request.

To create self-signed certificate you could use [`openssl`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/faq.html#USER4) it is available on all major OSes.

```
$ openssl req -new -x509 -key privkey.pem -out cacert.pem -days 1095
```

If you'd like to do it using [M2Crypto](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/M2Crypto) then take a look at [`X509TestCase.test_mkcert()` method](https://gitlab.com/m2crypto/m2crypto/blob/17f7ca77afa75cedaa60bf3db767119adba4a2ec/tests/test_x509.py#L237).

Comment: Yay, a unit test that does it. Thank you, I'll look into that. As for openssl I am not sure how I can call that from python, making sure that it's available.

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar - but trying to avoid writing files as much as possible - I'd rather store the data in a database.

Comment: The OP asked for platform independence: `so that it is platform independent` You can't expect everyone to have openssl installed on their machines.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the openssl method that J.F. Sebastian stated from within Python.

Import the OS lib and call the command like this:

```
os.system("openssl req -new -x509 -key privkey.pem -out cacert.pem -days 1095")
```

If it requires user interaction, it might work if you run it via subprocess pipe and allow for raw input to answer any prompts.

Comment: The OP asked for platform independence: `so that it is platform independent` You can't expect everyone to have openssl installed on their machines.