# How to create self-signed SSL certificate in pure python? (Without any additional installation like openssl or mkcert)

Tags: python, django, ssl, self-signed, self-signed-certificate

There are similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360654/create-self-signed-ssl-certificates-in-python) which did not have any good answer, or linked to [scripts](http://sunh11373.blogspot.com/2007/04/python-utility-for-converting.html) that were very old.

I have an open-source web app made using django that people can install on their local networks. I want to implement a quick, automated set up of the web app, with minimal technical know-how. One of the tasks involved is generating self-signed SSL certificates. However, since I **do not** know in advance what OS they would be using, I wish the certificate stuff to be done **exclusively using python**, to ensure platform independence. *Common methods like using OpenSSL includes OS-specific installation of those libraries, which I do not want*.

How can I make secure self-signed ssl certificates exclusively through python and no additional installations like OpenSSL or mkcert?

Comment: Although possible in a theoretica sense, likely not feasible in a practical sense: certificates are complicated and hard to get right, therefore these are often implemented in libraries that often depend on other libraries with crypto algorithms. For example `mkcert` is implemented with dependencies to the `crypto` library: https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert/blob/master/cert.go since it is hard to get the details right.

Comment: The obvious answer to your question is: by writing a lot of code to do it. Since all the relevant standards are well-documented, what is your real question?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thank you, understood. One alternative I'm considering is to download the caddy server through a python script; the download api can give the software in a single file for the current OS, and running the server will create a certificate on its own.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk thank you, I am well aware of that. The question was, is there an easy, automate-able way to do it.