# OpenSSL x509 Certificate: Add Extension with X509_add1_ext_i2d()

Tags: objective-c, c, ssl, openssl, x509certificate

### Context:

I'm generating an x509 Certificate using APIs in OpenSSL. I first create the X509 structure like this:

```
X509 *x509 = X509_new();   // Assume no errors
```

---

### What I'm trying to do:

Now I want to add an extension to this Certificate. Specifically, I want to set the "Extended Key Usage" extension to the value `serverAuth,clientAuth`. To do this, I am attempting to use the OpenSSL function `x509_add1_ext_i2d()`, which has the following signature:

```
X509_add1_ext_i2d(X509 *x, int nid, void *value, int crit, unsigned long flags)
```

I'm calling that function passing a C-String for `value`, which I assume is not correct. Here's the call I'm making:

```
X509_add1_ext_i2d(x509, NID_ext_key_usage, "serverAuth,clientAuth", 0, 0)
```

---

### What's Happening:

I'm getting an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_i386_GPFLT)` exception when that line of code runs. I'm assuming that's because the `value` I pass in has to be some sort of special thing (an octet string? Some sort of other OpenSSL value?)

---

### What I Need:

What do I need to pass for the `value` parameter in order to correctly set that extension to the string value `serverAuth,clientAuth`? Or, alternately, why am I getting the listed exception? Note: If I remove this line and attempt to generate a certificate without extensions (with other properties such as Name, expiration date, etc. that I have excluded here for brevity) it works just fine.

I have spent an entire day pouring over OpenSSL's (ridiculously poor) documentation and Googling. Everything I can find discusses how to add extensions to certificates from the command line rather than in code. I cannot track down what the hell this function expects to see in the `value` parameter.

Comment: So the "i2d" in the function apparently means, in OpenSSL-speak, "internal to DER", meaning that the value parameter is supposed to be some internal OpenSSL structure. The thing I can't figure out is...which structure? An ASN1_Octet_String? Tried it—doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some more rooting around in OpenSSL's source, I stumbled across a function in the `makecert.c` example that also does this. I've cleaned it up slightly, and here it is. You pass in the NID of the extension you want to set and a simple string value for it. Very handy:

```
BOOL addExtension(X509 *cert, int nid, char *value)
{
    X509_EXTENSION *ex = NULL;
    X509V3_CTX ctx;

    // This sets the 'context' of the extensions. No configuration database
    X509V3_set_ctx_nodb(&ctx);

    // Issuer and subject certs: both the target since it is self signed, no request and no CRL
    X509V3_set_ctx(&ctx, cert, cert, NULL, NULL, 0);
    ex = X509V3_EXT_conf_nid(NULL, &ctx, nid, value);
    if (!ex) {
        return NO;
    }

    int result = X509_add_ext(cert, ex, -1);

    X509_EXTENSION_free(ex);

    return (result == 0) ? YES : NO;
}
```