# How to programmatically create a Certificate Signing Request (CSR)?

Tags: c, ssl, openssl, pki, csr

How to implement it in C?

`openssl req -new -key cert.key -out cert.csr`

```
openssl x509 -req -in cert.csr -CA rootCA.crt -CAkey rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out cert.crt -days 5000
```

Comment: Download the source of OpenSSL, find the function that's responsible for generating it, and paste it to your project, along with all of its dependencies. Or compile it in a lib file and link that to your project.

Comment: See Nathan Osman's answer at [Programmatically Create X509 Certificate using OpenSSL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/256405). Also see the source code for the `openssl x509` subcommand at `<openssl src>/apps/x509.c`. For the subcommand, the only difference between a self-signed certificate and a CSR is the `-req` option.

Comment: @jww I certainly have the same question as OP, and the comments and link provided certainly do not say anything about CSR. Can you please re-open this question?

Comment: @Petr - Two upvotes on the suggestion... Done. Sorry about the late reply.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I hope it is not too late and my answer will help :)

I'm providing my solution, which I implemented ~three years ago after researching openssl sources. The generated certs are very simple - review which fields you need and adjust the functions.

```
openssl req -new -key cert.key -out cert.csr
```

is implemented the following way:

```
X509_REQ *generate_cert_req(const char *p_path) {
    FILE *p_file = NULL;
    EVP_PKEY *p_key = NULL;
    X509_REQ *p_x509_req = NULL;

    if (NULL == (p_file = fopen(p_path, "r"))) {
        printf("failed to open the private key file\n");
        goto CLEANUP;
    }

    if (NULL == (p_key = PEM_read_PrivateKey(p_file, NULL, NULL, NULL))) {
        printf("failed to read the private key file\n");
        goto CLEANUP;
    }

    if (NULL == (p_x509_req = X509_REQ_new())) {
        printf("failed to create a new X509 REQ\n");
        goto CLEANUP;
    }

    if (0 > X509_REQ_set_pubkey(p_x509_req, p_key)) {
        printf("failed to set pub key\n");
        X509_REQ_free(p_x509_req);
        p_x509_req = NULL;
        goto CLEANUP;
    }

    if (0 > X509_REQ_sign(p_x509_req, p_key, EVP_sha256())) {
        printf("failed to sign the certificate\n");
        X509_REQ_free(p_x509_req);
        p_x509_req = NULL;
        goto CLEANUP;
    }

    CLEANUP:
    fclose(p_file);
    EVP_PKEY_free(p_key);

    return p_x509_req;
}
```

the function has only one argument which is a path to a key file (cert.key in the openssl command snippet above) and as its result returns a pointer to a generated certificate request.

```
openssl x509 -req -in cert.csr -CA rootCA.crt -CAkey rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out cert.crt -days 5000
```

is implemented as the "generate_cert" function

```
int randSerial(ASN1_INTEGER *ai) {
    BIGNUM *p_bignum = NULL;
    int ret = -1;

    if (NULL == (p_bignum = BN_new())) {
        goto CLEANUP;
    }

    if (!BN_pseudo_rand(p_bignum, 64, 0, 0)) {
        goto CLEANUP;
    }

    if (ai && !BN_to_ASN1_INTEGER(p_bignum, ai)) {
        goto CLEANUP;
    }

    ret = 1;

    CLEANUP:
    BN_free(p_bignum);

    return ret;
}

X509 *generate_cert(X509_REQ *pCertReq, const char *p_ca_path, const char *p_ca_key_path) {
    FILE *p_ca_file = NULL;
    X509 *p_ca_cert = NULL;
    EVP_PKEY *p_ca_pkey = NULL;
    FILE *p_ca_key_file = NULL;
    EVP_PKEY *p_ca_key_pkey = NULL;
    X509 *p_generated_cert = NULL;
    ASN1_INTEGER *p_serial_number = NULL;
    EVP_PKEY *p_cert_req_pkey = NULL;

    if (NULL == (p_ca_file = fopen(p_ca_path, "r"))) {
        printf("failed to open the ca file\n");
        goto CLEANUP;
    }

    if (NULL == (p_ca_cert = PEM_read_X509(p_ca_file, NULL, 0, NULL))) {
        printf("failed to read X509 CA certificate\n");
        goto CLEANUP;
    }

    if (NULL == (p_ca_pkey = X509_get_pubkey(p_ca_cert))) {
        printf("failed to get X509 CA pkey\n");
        goto CLEANUP;
    }

    if (NULL == (p_ca_key_file = fopen(p_ca_key_path, "r"))) {
        printf("failed to open the private key file\n");
        goto CLEANUP;
    }

    if (NULL == (p_ca_key_pkey = PEM_read_PrivateKey(p_ca_key_file, NULL, NULL, NULL))) {
        printf("failed to read the private key file\n");
        goto CLEANUP;
    }

    if (NULL == (p_generated_cert = X509_new())) {
        printf("failed to allocate a new X509\n");
        goto CLEANUP;
    }

    p_serial_number = ASN1_INTEGER_new();
    randSerial(p_serial_number);
    X509_set_serialNumber(p_generated_cert, p_serial_number);

    X509_set_issuer_name(p_generated_cert, X509_REQ_get_subject_name(pCertReq));
    X509_set_subject_name(p_generated_cert, X509_REQ_get_subject_name(pCertReq));

    X509_gmtime_adj(X509_get_notBefore(p_generated_cert), 0L);
    X509_gmtime_adj(X509_get_notAfter(p_generated_cert), 31536000L);

    if (NULL == (p_cert_req_pkey = X509_REQ_get_pubkey(pCertReq))) {
        printf("failed to get certificate req pkey\n");
        X509_free(p_generated_cert);
        p_generated_cert = NULL;
        goto CLEANUP;
    }

    if (0 > X509_set_pubkey(p_generated_cert, p_cert_req_pkey)) {
        printf("failed to set pkey\n");
        X509_free(p_generated_cert);
        p_generated_cert = NULL;
        goto CLEANUP;
    }

    if (0 > EVP_PKEY_copy_parameters(p_ca_pkey, p_ca_key_pkey)) {
        printf("failed to copy parameters\n");
        X509_free(p_generated_cert);
        p_generated_cert = NULL;
        goto CLEANUP;
    }

    X509_set_issuer_name(p_generated_cert, X509_get_subject_name(p_ca_cert));

    if (0 > X509_sign(p_generated_cert, p_ca_key_pkey, EVP_sha256())) {
        printf("failed to sign the certificate\n");
        X509_free(p_generated_cert);
        p_generated_cert = NULL;
        goto CLEANUP;
    }

    CLEANUP:
    fclose(p_ca_file);
    X509_free(p_ca_cert);
    EVP_PKEY_free(p_ca_pkey);
    fclose(p_ca_key_file);
    EVP_PKEY_free(p_ca_key_pkey);
    ASN1_INTEGER_free(p_serial_number);
    EVP_PKEY_free(p_cert_req_pkey);

    return p_generated_cert;
}
```

the function has three arguments:

1: is a point to a certificate request (generated in the first step)

2: a path to ca (-CA rootCA.crt in the command snippet above)

3: a path to ca key (-CAkey rootCA.key)

the functions can be used the following way:

```
int save_cert_req(X509_REQ *p_cert_req, const char *path) {
    FILE *p_file = NULL;
    if (NULL == (p_file = fopen(path, "w"))) {
        printf("failed to open file for saving csr\n");
        return -1;
    }

    PEM_write_X509_REQ(p_file, p_cert_req);
    fclose(p_file);
    return 0;
}

int save_cert(X509 *p_generated_cert, const char *path) {
    FILE *p_file = NULL;
    if (NULL == (p_file = fopen(path, "w"))) {
        printf("failed to open file for saving csr\n");
        return -1;
    }

    PEM_write_X509(p_file, p_generated_cert);
    fclose(p_file);
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int ret = 0;
    X509_REQ *p_cert_req = NULL;
    X509 *p_generated_cert = NULL;

    p_cert_req = generate_cert_req(CERT_REQUEST_KEY_PATH);
    if (NULL == p_cert_req) {
        printf("failed to generate cert req\n");
        ret = -1;
        goto CLEANUP;
    }

    if (save_cert_req(p_cert_req, GENERATED_CERT_REQUEST_SAVE_PATH)) {
        printf("failed to save generated cert request\n");
        ret = -1;
        goto CLEANUP;
    }

    p_generated_cert = generate_cert(p_cert_req, CERT_CA_PATH, CERT_CA_KEY_PATH);
    if (NULL == p_generated_cert) {
        printf("failed to generate cert\n");
        ret = -1;
        goto CLEANUP;
    }

    if (save_cert(p_generated_cert, GENERATED_CERT_SAVE_PATH)) {
        printf("failed to save generated cert\n");
        ret = -1;
        goto CLEANUP;
    }

    printf("the certificates have been generated.");

    CLEANUP:
    X509_REQ_free(p_cert_req);
    X509_free(p_generated_cert);

    return ret;
}
```

You can download the whole solution that you can compile and test from github repository:
https://github.com/egorovandreyrm/openssl_cert_req

Comment: What is the purpose of `p_ca_pkey`? It seems it's not really used.

Comment: Bugs in errors checking: should be `0 >= ` instead of `0 >`.

Comment: Why is there two `X509_set_issuer_name`s?