# OpenSSL: How to code in C signing CSR with CA

Tags: c, openssl

I have created the CA certificate with OpenSSL commands and it is in a PEM file.

In my program I have created the RSA key pair and the CSR (X509_REQ type).

Now, how do I sign the CSR with the CA implementing it in C language?

Thanks.

Comment: You have the CA private key as well, right? You're going to need it. That said, I think you're going to find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38949576/how-to-programmatically-create-a-certificate-signing-request-csr) *extremely* informative.

Comment: Do you mean the private key generated as a previous step before the generation of the CA cert file?

Comment: I mean signing *anything* requires the private key of the *signer*. If you're generating a cert from the CSR you need the CA's private key to do it. II meant what I said, btw. The linked answer I provided is highly informative on multiple fronts, and probably shows exactly what you're looking for. Likewise [for this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256405/programmatically-create-x509-certificate-using-openssl).

Comment: I think the initial link is what I need. Thanks a lot for your help! I have another question: before signing the certificate on generate_cert function, there is a call to a function named EVP_KEY_copy_parameters... is that actually needed since the "to" key of the function isn't used to sign the certificate?