# How to create CA, Intermediate and device certificate using openssl command?

Tags: ssl, cryptography, x509

I want to create CA, Intermediate and Device certificate using openssl APIs.

Comment: This is too broad and shows no real research by your own. You might start with [Programmatically Create X509 Certificate using OpenSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256405/programmatically-create-x509-certificate-using-openssl) which was the first hit when searching for [openssl api create certificate](https://www.google.com/search?q=opensl+api+create+certificate) and if you still have problems then please ask more specific questions.

Comment: Don't use OpenSSL directly for your task, you should use CA server software instead.